# How can I install create_csv on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________thanks the problem is solved

Comment: Have you looked at the online documentation for python? Please describe what you've tried so far and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have Python3 installed then you just need to install the `python-csv` package:

```
[user@ubuntu ~] sudo python3 -m pip install python-csv
```

Once you've installed that, you can run your script:

```
[user@ubuntu ~] python3 your_script.py
```